# create a database dynamically in mysql using spring boot and JPA Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to create a data dynamically in MySql using springBoot and JPA.

In Detail:
There will be a mater DataBase where the all the DataBase names will be stored. Based on a request(webservice) to the application, the application checks in the masterDB is the name of the DB is present in the master DB-table. If the name is exists in the master Db-table. Then the application need to connect to that db and fetch the details from that. If not exists then it need to Create the Db with that name with all the predefined tables and had to insert that name in to the master DB and need to connect to the DB.

Comment: Do you want to switch database or schema?

Comment: database only (example :  create Database MasterDb);